# using an ID before it is created sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i have a question about mysql

this is my query:

```
$geboortedatum = $_POST['dag'].'-'.$_POST['maand'].'-'.$_POST['jaar'];
$geboortedatum1 = $_POST['dag1'].'-'.$_POST['maand1'].'-'.$_POST['jaar1'];
try{                                                                    
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);                                                                   

    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO clienten 
        (client_voornaam,
        client_achternaam,
        client_geboortedatum,
        client_geslacht,
        client_adres,
        client_postcode,
        client_woonplaats,
        client_contactpersoon,
        client_diagnose,
        datun_aanmaak)
        VALUES (:voornaam,
        :achternaam.
        :geboortedatum,
        :geslacht,
        :adres,
        :postcode,
        :woonplaats,
        :contactpersoon,
        :diagnose,
        :datumaanmaak)
        INSERT INTO verzorgers(
        wat_is_verzorger,
        voornaam_verzorger,
        achternaam_verzorger,
        geboortedatum_verzorger,
        email_verzorger,
        geslacht_verzorger,
        adres_verzorger,
        postcode_verzorger,
        woontplaats_verzorger,
        tel1_verzorger,
        tel2_verzorger,
        datum_aanmaak
        )
        VALUES(
        :watisverz
        :voornaamverz,
        :achternaamverz,
        :geboortedatumverz,
        :emailverz,
        :geslachtverz:
        :adresverz,
        :postcodeverz,
        :woonplaatsverz,
        :tel1verz,
        :tel2verz,
        :datumaanmaak
        )
        ";                                                              

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);                                         

    $stmt->bindParam(':voornaam', $_POST['voornaam'], PDO::PARAM_STR);                  
    $stmt->bindParam(':achternaam', $_POST['achternaam'], PDO::PARAM_STR);                  
    $stmt->bindParam(':geboortedatum', $geboortedatum, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':geslacht', $_POST['geslacht'], PDO::PARAM_STR);                  
    $stmt->bindParam(':adres', $_POST['adres'], PDO::PARAM_STR);                    
    $stmt->bindParam(':postcode', $_POST['postcode'], PDO::PARAM_INT);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':woonplaats', $_POST['woonplaats'], PDO::PARAM_STR);                  
    $stmt->bindParam(':contactpersoon', $_POST['contactpersoon'], PDO::PARAM_STR);                  
    $stmt->bindParam(':diagnose', $_POST['diagnose'], PDO::PARAM_INT);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':datumaanmaak', $_POST['datum_toetreding'], PDO::PARAM_INT);                                                                      

        $stmt->execute();                                               

}                                                                       
catch(PDOException $e)                                                  
{                                                                       
    echo '<pre>';                                                       
    echo 'Regel: '.$e->getLine().'<br>';                                
    echo 'Bestand: '.$e->getFile().'<br>';                              
    echo 'Foutmelding: '.$e->getMessage();                              
    echo '</pre>';                                                      
}   ?>
```

Now when the client and verzorger are created, they both get an unique ID.
Client had a column that stores the verzorger ID associated and vica versa.
Is it possible to make a query that also directly stores the IDs created?

EDIT:
ok maybe to difficult, maybe an answer to get only the client id in verzorger?:)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this (TableAID and TableBID are both AUTO_INCREMENT columns):

```
INSERT INTO TableA
(SomeColumn)
VALUES
('Blah');

SET @TableAID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO TableB
(TableAID, AnotherColumn)
VALUES
(@TableAID,'Foobar');

SET @TableBID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

UPDATE TableA
SET TableBID = @TableBID
WHERE TableAID = @TableAID;
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is create a function that queries against a sequence generator:

```
create function foo  returns int
Begin 
   Declare nextValue int
   Set nextValue = SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR mySequence;
End
return (nextValue);
```

Which would allow you to pass around the value returned from this sequence and you could know "ahead" of time what the values were going to be.

**EDIT**

Please understand how concurrency works and use either pessimistic or optimistic locking.  While this should be obvious, some feel as though it is necessary to include.

Comment: Doesn't this introduce problems with race conditions?  MySQL must have a better approach.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what race condition would that be?  I use this approach currently and after trillions of persists have never had a failure.

Comment: If two threads are attempting to insert into the table at the same time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is where Pessimistic versus Optimistic locking comes into play.

Comment: Please don't do this. **Ever**. This is why people will invent time machines and send robots through them to hunt you down.

Comment: @tadman you can't just arbitrarily say dont do something, you need to give a reason why.  If you can think of a more correct way of getting an ID that is controlled by the system ONE time before it is used in MULTIPLE places I would love to see it.   I would also like it if you could go through all of SO where this type of question has been asked before and spray forth nonsense.

Comment: The only pattern that's reliable and effective is to *reserve* your number in advance. It can be tricky to do this in a way that's not convoluted, but it's the only way to be sure you don't have some crazy race condition. Bugs of that sort are extremely annoying to track down, and when you find out that someone was just being lazy by not doing it right, exceptionally rage inducing. Insert the minimum required to claim the ID, then update it later if you must.

Comment: @tadman it doesn't cause a race condition, if you have locking configured correctly.

Comment: @tadman source being,  I do this in a production system that handles trillions of inserts

Comment: Your example doesn't define any locking, so if you could add that it would make it a viable solution instead of the crazy-pants snippet you have there that's reckless to use in isolation.

Comment: @tadman edited to add a line about locking, so I don't crush junior DBAs who run billion dollar systems =p